# Program not throwing signature violation error even though signature ID differs from program object to service progam

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I have binded one service program to a program object. Initially both have same signature IDs. Later on, I added a new module to the list of modules currently existing in service program. At this point of time both program and service program have different signature IDs.

Program signature ID:

```
     Service                                                                
Opt  Program     Library     Activation  Signature                          
     SRVPGM1     AKSHAYM     *IMMED      00000000000000000000FE56D41B36D1
```

Service program signature ID:

```
   Shared activation group  . . . . . . . . . . . . :   *NO                     
   Current export signature . . . . . . . . . . . . :   0000000000D5D6C72E980395
EE694617                                                                        
   User profile . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . :   *USER                   
                                                                        More...
```

Now, when I issued STRDBG and CALL to that program. I am not getting signature violation error.

Am I missing anything here. Can someone please help me on this ?

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the service program signature ID in the same library that the program is?

Answer (score 3):

Hit enter a couple times on the `DSPSRVPGM` command output till you get to the **Signatures** screen or just use `DSPSRVPGM SRVPGM(...) DETAIL(*SIGNATURE)`

[image: DSPSRVPGM - Signatures]

Sounds like the prior signature is still valid.

This is enabled by the use of a `STRPGMEXP  PGMLVL(*PRV)` block in the binder source used to create the *SRVPGM object.  The idea is that you can add new exports to a *SRVPGM without forcing a recompile of existing callers.

However, the use of `PGMLVL(*PRV)` doesn't really add any value.  Just adds complexity to the binder source.

Best practice for ILE is to

- Use a hardcoded signature, `STRPGMEXP PGMLVL(*CURRENT) SIGNATURE('MYSRV v1')`
- Add new procedures to the end of the export list
- don't delete exports or change the order of the binder source export list
- if making changes to an existing procedure, don't change existing parms and add new ones as `OPTION(*NOPASS)`

Following the rules above, your service program can be enhanced without needing to recomplie or otherwise affecting any existing programs that calls procedures in it.  You have to follow the last 3 rules above even with a `PGMLVL(*PRV)` block.  Thus: it's simpler and easier to just use hardcoded signatures.

If at some point you have to force callers to be recompiled, then simply change the *SRVPGM signature,
`STRPGMEXP PGMLVL(*CURRENT) SIGNATURE('MYSRV v2')`

References: [ILE Concepts for RPG presentation by IBM's Barbara Morris](https://www.semiug.org/2010/docs/ile_concepts_for_rpg.pdf)

> I recommend adding a comment at the beginning about adding new exports at the end, as well as putting numbers in comments for each export, to reinforce the idea that the order must not change.
>
> You set the signature using the SIGNATURE parameter of the STRPGMEXP command
>
> Ideally, the signature should never change.

Comment: Best practice is to add functionality is to a new service program.  You start doing the I can create a better signature dance and you will trip over your feet.

Comment: @danny117 are you saying add a new service program every time you need to add new procedures?  That's overkill...and a bad practice given that each service program activation takes resources.  (granted, with *DEFR...it's doesn't have to be all up front anymore.)   Again, with hardcoded signatures, you set them once and forget about them.  Take a look at IBM's service programs...all of them have a hardcoded signature (usually the *SRVPGM name)

Comment: There is no argument here.  If your adding add a service program zero business exposure.